# Grunt for Brackets Extension Not Working For me

Tags: gruntjs, text-editor, adobe-brackets

When I use this plugin, Grunt for Brackets, it doesn't seem to work for me. I've looked and looked and looked through the files of the extension, and when I "grunt," my devtools spit out this log.

```
[node-log 10:01:49 AM] { '0': { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' } }
```

I'm not exactly sure what that means...

[Here is a link to the extension.](https://github.com/dhategan/brackets-grunt)
The author has not updated anything in months, and there is an open issue ticket, however there hasn't been any responses.

If someone could help me decipher this log, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Btw, your link above went to the webpage for an Italian restaurant. I edited to replace it with https://github.com/dhategan/brackets-grunt - please update if that's not the extension you were talking about.

Comment: That is the correct one. Wonder why it sent it to the wrong link. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Grunt installed on your computer already? If so, is it installed in the standard location? (e.g. did you intsall using `npm -g grunt`?)

`ENOENT` basically means "file not found," and since the error message also says `spawn` I'm guessing the problem is it's unable to find the Grunt binary to execute.

---

***Update:*** Looks like a bug in how the current version of the extension was packaged. You should be able to fix it yourself this way:

1. *Help > Show Extensions Folder* in Brackets and find the brackets-grunt extension in the 'user' subfolder
2. Open a command prompt at that location
3. cd into the `node` folder inside the extension
4. Run `npm install`

I added a note to [the bug](https://github.com/dhategan/brackets-grunt/issues/34), so hopefully the extension's author will fix it soon too.

Comment: I have installed grunt in the default location: Open CMD then typed in 'npm -g grunt' with no problems.

I will try another grunt instal after removing all the associated grunt and node.js files

Comment: @Ishio It looks like a bug in the extension after all - see updated answer above with workaround.

Comment: After directing there to the path inside the extensions folder, i ran the install and just had the output of 'npm WARN package.json @ No Description/No repo field. No README data'

Comment: So I copied the files from the zip on there, and added the node. I went into it, 'npm install' gave me no package and installed grunt and grunt-cli. I refreshed the plugin, refreshed the application, and no change.

Comment: @Ishio You shouldn't have to copy or unzip anything if you already have the extension installed.  Are you on Mac? If so, go to `~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user` and you should see a folder for the extension _already there_ if the extension is installed. That's the folder you want - go into its `node` subfolder and run `npm install` there.

Comment: I installed the plugin, then just downloaded and cross referenced the plugin. I uninstalled it again, deleted the folder of whatever contents existed. I reinstalled via Brackets, went to the node through cmd in Windows, and ran 'npm install'

Comment: So does the folder `~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions/user/brackets-grunt/node/node_modules` exist now?  Does it have a `.bin/grunt` binary inside it? You can see the exact code that's trying to launch Grunt [here](https://github.com/dhategan/brackets-grunt/blob/master/node/GruntDomain.js#L134)...

Comment: Yeah it had that. I'm no longer at my desktop that has Brackets installation, but I will double check that tomorrow, and make sure my Main.js is pointing to the right location.

Comment: I uninstalled, and removed and instance of the plugin from the computer. Restarted the browser and reinstalled the plugin. I then followed the steps mentioned above again, and ran the install. [Here is the screen shot of the install and the console error still exists](http://i.imgur.com/cyRrhGb.png) I confirmed that grunt.cmd exists in .bin